# Trying to use a nested while loop in bash to print out numbers in an increasing order

Tags: linux, bash, unix, while-loop

I am trying to write a bash script that will take in a number of lines and print out each line with an additional number added on to it for each new line up until it reaches the number of lines that the user specified.

```sh
#!/bin/bash



printf "%0s\n" "Enter the number of lines"
read x

n=0
while [ "$n" -lt $x ];
do
        #
        y="$n"
        while [ 0 -le "$y" ];
        do
                printf "$y "
                let y--
        done
        echo 
        let n++
done
```

**Current Output for x=5:**

```
0 
1 0 
2 1 0 
3 2 1 0 
4 3 2 1 0
```

This is similar to want I want. I want it in the reverse order.
**Wanted output for x = 5:**

```
0
0 1
0 1 2
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
```

I have played around with the logic only to get blanks or an infinite loop of printf errors. I am new to this and would appreciate any help.

Comment: to reverse the order of the numbers just change your code to have `y` start with `0` and count up to `n`, eg: `y=0 ; while [ "${y}" -le "${n}" ]; do printf "$y "; let y++; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a simpler way:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter the number of lines: " x

for (( n = 1; n <= x; n++ )); do
    for (( y = 0; y < n; y++ )); do
        echo -n "$y "
    done
    echo
done
```

Output for x=5

```
0
0 1
0 1 2
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
```

I suppose the script is self-explanatory but if you have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: While I wish this was the case, I am supposed to use a nested while loop. I appreciate the example though! This does kind of help me understand the logic required to make it work. I still might be able to rework this to get a solution

Comment: Understood. It will not be a difficult task to convert the `for` loop into the equivalent `while` loop. Good luck!

Comment: To be clear, `for ((x; y; z)); do ...; done` is equivalent to `x; while y; do ... z; done`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to arrive at a solution using @markp-fuso's comment. It looks like this.

```sh
#!/bin/bash



printf "%0s\n" "Enter the number of lines"
read x

n=0
while [ "$n" -lt $x ];
do
        #
        y=0
        while [ $y -le "$n" ];
        do
                printf "$y "
                let y++
        done
        echo 
        let n++
done
```

**Output for x = 5**

```
0 
0 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 2 3 
0 1 2 3 4
```